# DateDiff to output hours and minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

my code gives TOTAL HOURS in hours, but i am trying to output something like

```
TotalHours 
  8:36
```

where 8 represents hour part and 36 represents minutes part mean totalHours a person has worked in a single day at office.

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
)
SELECT    EmplID
        , EmplName
        , InTime
        , [TimeOut]
        , [DateVisited]
        , DATEDIFF(Hour,InTime, [TimeOut]) TotalHours
from times
Order By EmplID, DateVisited
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Small change like this can be done

```
  SELECT  EmplID
        , EmplName
        , InTime
        , [TimeOut]
        , [DateVisited]
        , CASE WHEN minpart=0 
        THEN CAST(hourpart as nvarchar(200))+':00' 
        ELSE CAST((hourpart-1) as nvarchar(200))+':'+ CAST(minpart as nvarchar(200))END as 'total time'
        FROM 
        (
        SELECT   EmplID, EmplName, InTime, [TimeOut], [DateVisited],
        DATEDIFF(Hour,InTime, [TimeOut]) as hourpart, 
        DATEDIFF(minute,InTime, [TimeOut])%60 as minpart  
        from times) source
```

Comment: Wowwwwwww amazing, amazing sir, love u :)

Comment: Only one problem that totalHours column header has been disabled, it says NO COULUMN NAME :(

Comment: updating query for header as 'total time'

Comment: and sir @DhruvJoshi, please Expalin that what have you done, it's bit hard to understand your logiv

Comment: @VigneshKumar: which answer sir ?

Comment: I got the hour part and min part using datediff() function which gives int. Then casted int parts into strings(varchar(200)) and joined them for output. For the boundary case of diff between 9:00 and 16:00 when minpart =0 mins, I added the case statement. To make it look simple I selected hourpart and minpart (as integers) in inner query and then in outer query added the case statement

Comment: @user3207757 Check the answer in the name of Vignesh Kumar

Comment: @DhruvJoshi amazing, Lots of thanks, sir just explain it, that how it's working, i mean it's logic and some new keywords

Comment: @VigneshKumar oh great sir, it's working too :) but bit new to me, prety hard to understand :/

Comment: @user3207757 It's ok. Please upvote for others reference. It may help others

Comment: @user3207757: If you want details on answers, you can call me on phone, assuming you are in India. My profile contains phone number

Comment: @user3207757 both Dhruvjoshi and Vignesh Kumar's answer is easy to understand. What difficulty u find to understand them, they have mentioned each and everything perfectly

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian like 'minpart=0' etc, these things and yes they have expalined perfectly, going to choose both as answers

Answer (score 61):

Very simply:

```
CONVERT(TIME,Date2 - Date1)
```

For example:

```
Declare @Date2 DATETIME = '2016-01-01 10:01:10.022'
Declare @Date1 DATETIME = '2016-01-01 10:00:00.000'
Select CONVERT(TIME,@Date2 - @Date1) as ElapsedTime
```

Yelds:

```
ElapsedTime
----------------
00:01:10.0233333

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I up-voted this one because it actually helped me out today. Simple and clean and gives me just what I was looking for.

Comment: Excellent ! This should be the right answer. why would anyone be doing the other complex and possible buggy solutions?

Comment: Datetime2 can not be subtracted directly; you will get the following error: `Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator.`

Comment: If the difference returned is over 24 hours you will not get the desired output. This method will return the rest value of the difference devided by 24.

Comment: Worked for getting the hours and minutes on the diff for two dates with the same date.  Just want I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Try this query

```
select
    *,
    Days          = datediff(dd,0,DateDif),
    Hours         = datepart(hour,DateDif),
    Minutes       = datepart(minute,DateDif),
    Seconds       = datepart(second,DateDif),
    MS            = datepart(ms,DateDif)
from
    (select
         DateDif = EndDate-StartDate,
         aa.*
     from
         (  -- Test Data
          Select
              StartDate = convert(datetime,'20090213 02:44:37.923'),
              EndDate   = convert(datetime,'20090715 13:24:45.837')) aa
    ) a
```

**Output**

```
DateDif                  StartDate                EndDate                 Days Hours Minutes Seconds MS
-----------------------  -----------------------  ----------------------- ---- ----- ------- ------- ---
1900-06-02 10:40:07.913  2009-02-13 02:44:37.923  2009-07-15 13:24:45.837 152  10    40      7       913

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: thanks sir, waiting for my points to get up so i can UPVOTE your post

Comment: I like this solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I would make your final select as:

```
SELECT    EmplID
        , EmplName
        , InTime
        , [TimeOut]
        , [DateVisited]
        , CONVERT(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(minute,InTime, TimeOut)/60) + ':' +
          RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(minute,InTime,TimeOut)%60),2)
          as TotalHours
from times
Order By EmplID, DateVisited
```

Any solution trying to use `DATEDIFF(hour,...` is bound to be complicated (if it's correct) because `DATEDIFF` counts transitions - `DATEDIFF(hour,...09:59',...10:01')` will return 1 because of the transition of the hour from 9 to 10. So I'm just using `DATEDIFF` on minutes.

The above can still be subtly wrong if seconds are involved (it can slightly overcount because its counting minute transitions) so if you need second or millisecond accuracy you need to adjust the `DATEDIFF` to use those units and then apply suitable division constants (as per the hours one above) to just return hours and minutes.

Answer (score 10):

Just change the

```
DATEDIFF(Hour,InTime, [TimeOut]) TotalHours
```

part to

```
CONCAT((DATEDIFF(Minute,InTime,[TimeOut])/60),':',
       (DATEDIFF(Minute,InTime,[TimeOut])%60)) TotalHours
```

The /60 gives you hours, the %60 gives you the remaining minutes, and CONCAT lets you put a colon between them.

I know it's an old question, but I came across it and thought it might help if someone else comes across it.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the `Datediff` in MS by the number of ms in a day, cast to `Datetime`, and then to time:

```
Declare @D1 datetime = '2015-10-21 14:06:22.780', @D2 datetime = '2015-10-21 14:16:16.893'

Select  Convert(time,Convert(Datetime, Datediff(ms,@d1, @d2) / 86400000.0))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want 08:30 ( HH:MM) format then try this,

```
SELECT EmplID
    , EmplName
    , InTime
    , [TimeOut]
    , [DateVisited]
    ,  RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(minute,InTime, TimeOut)/60),2) + ':' +
      RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(minute,InTime,TimeOut)%60),2)
      as TotalHours from times Order By EmplID, DateVisited
```

Answer (score 1):

Please put your related value and try this :

```
declare @x int, @y varchar(200),
        @dt1 smalldatetime = '2014-01-21 10:00:00', 
        @dt2 smalldatetime = getdate()

set @x = datediff (HOUR, @dt1, @dt2)
set @y =  @x * 60 -  DATEDIFF(minute,@dt1, @dt2)
set @y = cast(@x as varchar(200)) + ':' + @y
Select @y
```

Answer (score 1):

**Difference Two Time in [hh:mm:ss]**

```
select FORMAT((CONVERT(datetime,'2021-12-01 19:24:40') - CONVERT(datetime,'2021-12-01 17:00:00')),'hh:mm:ss')DffTime
```

Answer (score 0):

this would hep you

```
 DECLARE @DATE1 datetime = '2014-01-22 9:07:58.923'
 DECLARE @DATE2 datetime = '2014-01-22 10:20:58.923'
 SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, @DATE1,@DATE2) ,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @DATE1,@DATE2) - (DATEDIFF(HOUR,@DATE1,@DATE2)*60)

 SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(HOUR, @DATE1,@DATE2) AS nvarchar(200)) +
        ':'+ CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @DATE1,@DATE2)  -
                 (DATEDIFF(HOUR,@DATE1,@DATE2)*60) AS nvarchar(200))
As TotalHours
```

Comment: Set `@Date1` to `'2014-01-22 9:47:58.923'` and observe that that is 1 hour and -27 minutes, by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since any DateTime can be cast to a float, and the decimal part of the number represent the time itself:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT CAST(CAST(@date AS FLOAT) - FLOOR(CAST(@date AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME
```

This will result a datetime like '1900-01-01 hour of the day' you can cast it as time, timestamp or even use convert to get the formatted time.

I guess this works in any version of SQL since cast a datetime to float is compatible since version 2005.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still searching for a query to display the difference in hr min and sec format:
(This will display the difference in this format:  2 hr 20 min 22 secs)

```
SELECT
CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)/ 60 as nvarchar(20)) + ' hrs ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)/60 as nvarchar(20)) + ' mins' +          CAST(DATEDIFF(second, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)% 60 as nvarchar(20))  + ' secs'
```

OR can be in the format as in the question:

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)/ 60 as nvarchar(20)) + ':' + CAST(DATEDIFF(second, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)/60 as nvarchar(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a variant that works for more than 24 hours.

```
DECLARE @sd DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/07/2022 11:10:00', 103)
DECLARE @ed DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/07/2022 13:20:05', 103)
Select Concat (
    DATEDIFF(DAY,   @sd, @ed), 'd ',
    DATEPART(Hour, CONVERT(Time,@ed - @sd)), 'h ',
    DATEPART(Minute, CONVERT(Time,@ed - @sd)), 'm ',
    DATEPART(Second, CONVERT(Time,@ed - @sd)), 's'
    )
```

Output:

```
3d 2h 10m 5s
```

Answer (score 0):

For people that has MySql version < 5.6 as me they don't have TIMESTAMPDIFF so, I wrote MYTSDIFF a function that accepts %s (%m or %i) for minutes %h flags to get the difference in seconds, minutes and hours between 2 timestamps.

Enjoy!

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS MYTSDIFF;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `MYTSDIFF`( date1 timestamp, date2 timestamp, fmt varchar(20))
returns varchar(20) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  declare secs smallint(2);
  declare mins smallint(2);
  declare hours int;
  declare total real default 0;
  declare str_total varchar(20);

  select cast( time_format( timediff(date1, date2), '%s') as signed) into secs;
  select cast( time_format( timediff(date1, date2), '%i') as signed) into mins;
  select cast( time_format( timediff(date1, date2), '%H') as signed) into hours;

  set total = hours * 3600 + mins * 60 + secs;  

  set fmt = LOWER( fmt);

  if fmt = '%m' or fmt = '%i' then
    set total = total / 60;
  elseif fmt = '%h' then
    set total = total / 3600;
  else
    /* Do nothing, %s is the default: */
    set total = total + 0;
  end if;

  select cast( total as char(20)) into str_total;
  return str_total;                  

  END$$
  DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to jump through hoops.  Subtracting Start from End essentially gives you the timespan
(combining Vignesh Kumar's and Carl Nitzsche's answers) :

```
SELECT *,
    --as a time object
    TotalHours = CONVERT(time, EndDate - StartDate),
    --as a formatted string
    TotalHoursText = CONVERT(varchar(20), EndDate - StartDate, 114)
FROM (
    --some test values (across days, but OP only cares about the time, not date)
    SELECT
        StartDate = CONVERT(datetime,'20090213 02:44:37.923'),
        EndDate   = CONVERT(datetime,'20090715 13:24:45.837')
) t
```

**Ouput**

```
StartDate               EndDate                 TotalHours       TotalHoursText
----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------- --------------------
2009-02-13 02:44:37.923 2009-07-15 13:24:45.837 10:40:07.9130000 10:40:07:913
```

See the full cast and convert options here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: do you mean that between 13th of february till 15th of july there are only 10 hours? hm - better check your results before posting!

Comment: @Teo, the multi-day span was used deliberately to highlight this exact behavior, and explicitly called out in my code comment. It is the same method used in the currently highest voted answer (but more verbose for illustrative purposes).