# How does this Time Difference Calculation work?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, datediff

I wanted to display the difference in HH:MM:SS between two `datetime` fields in SQL Server 2014.

I found a solution in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249778/datediff-to-output-hours-and-minutes/21250650). And it works perfectly.  But I want to understand the "why" of how this arrives at the correct answer.

T-SQL:

```
SELECT y.CustomerID ,
   y.createDate ,
   y.HarvestDate ,
   y.DateDif ,
   DATEDIFF ( DAY, 0, y.DateDif ) AS [Days] ,
   DATEPART ( HOUR, y.DateDif ) AS [Hours] ,
   DATEPART ( MINUTE, y.DateDif ) AS [Minutes]
FROM   (
       SELECT x.createDate - x.HarvestDate AS [DateDif] ,
              x.createDate ,
              x.HarvestDate ,
              x.CustomerID
       FROM   (
                  SELECT CustomerID ,
                         HarvestDate ,
                         createDate
                  FROM   dbo.CustomerHarvestReports
                  WHERE  HarvestDate >= DATEADD ( MONTH, -6, GETDATE ())
              ) AS [x]
   ) AS [y]
ORDER BY DATEDIFF ( DAY, 0, y.DateDif ) DESC;
```

Results:

```
1239090  2017-11-07 08:51:03.870  2017-10-14 11:39:49.540  1900-01-24 21:11:14.330  23  21  11
1239090  2017-11-07 08:51:04.823  2017-10-19 11:17:48.320  1900-01-19 21:33:16.503  18  21  33
1843212  2017-10-27 19:14:02.070  2017-10-21 10:49:57.733  1900-01-07 08:24:04.337  6   8   24
1843212  2017-10-27 19:14:03.057  2017-10-21 10:49:57.733  1900-01-07 08:24:05.323  6   8   24
```

The first column in Customer ID - the second and third columns are the columns I wanted to calculate the time difference between.  The third column is the difference between the two columns - and one of the points in the code in which I do not understand.

If you subtract two `datetime` fields like this `create date - harvestdate`, why does it default to the year 1900?

And regarding `DATEDIFF ( DAY, 0 , y.DateDiff)` - what does the 0 mean? Does the 0 set the date as '01-01-1900'?

It works - for that I am grateful.  I was hoping I could get an explanation as to why this behavior works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some comments that should explain it:

```
SELECT y.CustomerID ,
   y.createDate ,
   y.HarvestDate ,
   y.DateDif ,
   DATEDIFF ( DAY, 0, y.DateDif ) AS [Days] , -- calculates the number of whole days between 0 and the difference

   DATEPART ( HOUR, y.DateDif ) AS [Hours] , -- the number of hours between the two dates has already been cleverly
                                             -- calculated in [DateDif], therefore, all that is required is to extract
                                             -- that figure using DATEPART

   DATEPART ( MINUTE, y.DateDif ) AS [Minutes] -- same explanation as [Hours]
FROM   (
       SELECT x.createDate - x.HarvestDate AS [DateDif] , -- calculates the difference expressed as a datetime;
                                                          -- 0 is '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' as a datetime, so the
                                                          -- resulting datetime will be that plus the difference
              x.createDate ,
              x.HarvestDate ,
              x.CustomerID
       FROM   (
                  SELECT CustomerID ,
                         HarvestDate ,
                         createDate
                  FROM   dbo.CustomerHarvestReports
                  WHERE  HarvestDate >= DATEADD ( MONTH, -6, GETDATE ())
              ) AS [x]
   ) AS [y]
ORDER BY DATEDIFF ( DAY, 0, y.DateDif ) DESC;
```

Comment: Appreciate the response.  That does help me understand what is happening here.