# How to calculate time difference between 2 different DATETIME columns in order to display the output in the format of H:MM?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table I have created and inserted values in it:

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance
(
  ClockedIn  DATETIME, 
  ClockedOut DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO Attendance(ClockedIn, ClockedOut) 
VALUES ('20160101 09:30:00','20160101 18:30:00'),
('20160201 08:10:00','20160201 18:20:00')
```

Now I am trying to solve a query which will display a person who has attended or worked for how many hours on that particular date.
The query result that I want to should display something like which is shown below:

```
Clocked In                    Clocked Out                  Hours
2016-01-01 09:30:00.000       2016-01-01 18:30:00.000      9.00
2016-02-01 08:10:00.000       2016-02-01 18:20:00.000      10.10
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT ClockedIn, ClockedOut,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(HOUR,ClockedOut - ClockedIn)) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MINUTE,ClockedOut - ClockedIn)) AS 'Hours'
FROM Attendance
```

And I got the following output:

[image]

I almost got the result that I wanted but the only issue is I am getting 9:0 instead of 9:00.

I even tried replacing **MINUTE** with **MM** inside the **DATEPART**
and I got the following result:

[image]

As you can see from screenshot above, I got a wrong result.

What changes do I need to make in my existing query in order to display 9:00 instead of 9:0 ?

Comment: Tip #1 - **never** use `varchar` without a size. You must always specify the size else you can end up truncating your result. Tip 2, **never** assume regular arithmetic (+/-) etc will work on datetime. Use the correct functions. Tip #3 you can't get the different of hours and minutes separately and expect the correct result.

Comment: You're assuming that both the hours and minutes parts are going to bigger at the clockout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateDiff to output hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249778/datediff-to-output-hours-and-minutes)

Comment: `MM` is `MONTH`, not `MINUTE`, so no idea why you would try that. [Shorthand is highly discouraged](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) anyway (for this exact reason). Also, ave you tested any solution you came up with for differences > 12 or 24 hours? Or where the minutes in ClockedIn < minutes in ClockedOut? Or hours in ClockedIn > hours in ClockedOut (e.g. shift from 11 AM to 3 PM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that your times are in whole minutes and that you might exceed a duration of 23:59. Here's a way that avoids invoking `format()`:

```
concat(
    datediff(second, ClockedIn, ClockedOut) / 3600, ':',
    right('0' + cast(datediff(second, ClockedIn, ClockedOut) % 3600 / 60 as varchar(2)), 2)
)
```

The trick for zero-padding it to add in the extra 0 but then trim it down to the number you really want.

Comment: Have a look at my answer.
I managed to solve it in a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, which is longer, but maybe clearer to see what is going on, you can split out the calculations using `CROSS APPLY` to avoid repeating them. And you can if you wish convert to a datatime in order to make use of `FORMAT` which allows full control over formatting.

```
SELECT ClockedIn, ClockedOut
   -- Pad out missing zeros and display.
   , RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),C2.Hh),2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),C2.Mm),2) [Hours 1]
   -- Optional, convert to a datetime datatype and then use FORMAT for full control over formatting
   , FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime2(0), RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),C2.Hh),2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),C2.Mm),2) + ':00'), 'HH:mm') [Hours 2]
FROM Attendance A
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Calculate seconds, because its a lower unit then the lowest required
    VALUES (CONVERT(int, DATEDIFF(second, A.ClockedIn, A.ClockedOut) * 1.0 / 60))
) C1 (DiffInMinutes)
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Calculates hours and minutes
    VALUES (C1.DiffInMinutes / 60, C1.DiffInMinutes % 60)
) C2 (Hh, Mm);
```

Returns:

| ClockedIn | ClockedOut | Hours 1 | Hours 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 09:30:00.000 | 2016-01-01 18:30:00.000 | 09:00 | 09:00 |
| 2016-02-01 08:10:00.000 | 2016-02-01 18:20:00.000 | 10:10 | 10:10 |

Comment: You may refer to my Answer as I have managed to solve it in the simplest possible way.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use your method but if it works for you great.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach (linebreaks added only for clarity):

```sql
select *, 
    cast(
        dateadd(
            minute, 
            datediff(
                minute,
                ClockedIn,
                ClockedOut
            ),
            '00:00'
        )
        as time(0)
    )
from dbo.Attendance;
```

Comment: With the caveat that it only works up to '23:59', right?

Comment: That's correct. But the OP said "how many hours on *that particular date*" (emphasis mine) so I felt that was a safe assumption to make.

Answer (score -1):

I have finally solved it

This is what I have done:

```
SELECT ClockedIn, ClockedOut,
    FORMAT((CONVERT(DATETIME,ClockedOut) - CONVERT(DATETIME,ClockedIn)),'h:mm') AS 'Hours'
FROM Attendance
```

And I got my desired output:

[image]

Comment: Just a word of caution, format() has some great functionality, but it is notoriously slow.  Also, there is no need to convert datetime if already datetime.    consider  convert(varchar(5),ClockedOut - ClockedIn,108)

Comment: it's good that you came up with a solution. My approach was to avoid using format function which is slow.

Comment: John Cappelletti ... Thanks for the information :)
Just one question:
Why did you add 5 for the VARCHAR ?

Comment: @pro_data because as I said in the comments, your should **always** specify the size of your `varchar`. Otherwise if often defaults to a length of 1.

Comment: Thanks Dale K ... really appreciate it :)

Comment: Also its not best practice to assume mathematical functions e.g. `-` work on datatime datatypes. Hence why our solutions rely on datediff.

Comment: Use format `H:mm` to at least get this to work for a full day otherwise 0 hours is reflected as 12 hours and it is useful only for the range 00:01 to 11:59.